# How to expand list of IP Address in a file from x.x.x.x-x.x.x.x to x.x.x.x-x format?

Tags: python, bash, awk

IP range of `10.0.0.1-10.0.0.3` can be expanded to

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

by using this script

```
eval printf '%s\\n' $(echo '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.3' | awk -F'[.-]' -v OFS='.' '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++) $i = "{" $i ".." $(i+4) "}"; NF=4} 1')
```

But if I've a set of data like this;

```
10.0.0.1-10.0.0.3
172.16.0.3
192.168.0.2-192.168.0.2
```

how do I produce output like this?

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
172.16.0.3
192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="-"
  OFS="."
}
$1==$2 || NF==1{
  print $1
  next
}
{
  num1=split($1,arr1,".")
  num2=split($2,arr2,".")
  for(i=arr1[num1];i<=arr2[num2];i++){
     print arr1[1],arr1[2],arr1[3],i
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                    ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="-"                                  ##Setting field separator as - here. 
  OFS="."                                 ##Setting output field separator as . here.
}
$1==$2 || NF==1{                          ##Checking condition if 1st field is equal to 2nd field OR number of fields is 1 then do following.
  print $1                                ##Printing 1st field of current line here.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  num1=split($1,arr1,".")                 ##Splitting $1 into arr1 with delimiter . AND num1 will have total number of elements in arr1.
  num2=split($2,arr2,".")                 ##Splitting $2 into arr2 with delimiter . AND num2 will have total number of elements in arr1.
  for(i=arr1[num1];i<=arr2[num2];i++){    ##Running for loop from last value of 1st field to last value of 2nd field.
     print arr1[1],arr1[2],arr1[3],i      ##Printing arr1 1st, 2nd and 3rd value and then printing value of i here.
  }
}' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```